# Best database with compression and FTS for Java

Tags: java, database, full-text-search, nosql, embedded-database

Suggest me an embedded database engine(for Java) to store 1000000 records in minimum time. 
It should provide the full text search facility (Actually i want Firefox's Awesome-bar like FTS searching used to search any combination of characters)
The database should be stored in compressed format on disk.

It **should not be `GPL`**. Apache 2.0 will be better.

Suggestions are open for NOSQL too.

Comment: It's `Java`, not `JAVA`. Also: "best" by what criteria?

Comment: "Best" for insertion and FTS retrieval. Please remove that -1.

Comment: So, did you already have a look at some databases?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com): in embedded mode stores, on my notebook, 1,000,000 of records in 4-30 seconds depending on the record type. It has a FullText index and it's 100% Java and has Apache 2 license.

Seems perfect, don't you? :-)

Comment: OrientDB is a nice option but the main problem with OrientDB is the lack of tutorial and examples also the javadocs are not so informative.

Comment: You can find a really simple example here: https://github.com/jbellmann/orientdb-examples/blob/master/src/de/jbellmann/orientdb/OrientTest.java

Answer (score 0):

One million records is not that many.  You can use a Map for records and a NavigableMap for the text search.  You can store the data on disk using a DeflatorOutputStream and InflatorInputStream.

Comment: looks interesting. Please give a link to the examples or tutorials for using map for records.

Comment: I would start with http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html for more http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+map+tutorial 31.7 million results.